# Airflow status when file not found in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow

I have an Airflow DAG, with a S3 Sensor task to look for new files on S3.
If the file is not there, at first it was marking the Task and DAG as 'FAILED'.

So I changed my DAG args to `soft_fail=True,`. In the logs I see that now it is marked as `SUCCESS`. Also, in the console, when I pull up the DAG runs, the DAG runs are marked as `SUCCESS`. This is not exactly what I was hoping for:

```
INFO - Poking for key : s3://inbox/test.txt
INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
INFO - Snap. Time is OUT.
INFO - Marking task as SKIPPED.dag_id=download-from-s3, task_id=...
INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.dag_id=download-from-s3, task_id=...
INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

I'm hoping to clearly see a distinction when pulling up the Dag runs in the UI for the following cases:

1. `Actual failures`, because of error or validations within the DAG perhaps (Status=FAILED)
2. `No file found` (Status = SKIPPED) or perhaps a more applicable or custom status like (Status=Done or Status=NO_FILE_FOUND). This would be ideal
3. `Success`, this would be when a file was found and no error occurred when parsing or moving it.

Any Apache Airflow experts out there that could demystify or shine some light on how to do this?

Comment: you can't create custom statuses for tasks. It's not very clear to me what you try to achieve (for example: if you don't want to wait for the file to land in S3 why do you even need to use sensor?). Can you write the use case of what you want (pseudo code)?

Comment: it seems that soft_fail should do what you are looking for.  instead of timeout, it should skip.  and other errors will be raised   not sure why it's not working for you --- what version you on?